# In React Native + Expo Keyboard pushing Header when scrolling screen to avoid hiding an input (Android only)

Tags: react-native, expo, keyboard

Current behavior
When keyboard appears and scrolls the screen so it doesn't hide the input, it pushes too the screen header. Here's a video of that behaviour:

[Header pushed upwards when keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0rDr.jpg)

I already set softwareKeyboardLayoutMode: 'pan', in my app.config file, and im wraping the scroll view that contains the form with  but it is enabled only for iOS

I tried with varius options for KeyboardAvoidingView but the behaviour is the same or worst (the keayboard doesn't push the header but hides the input)